# How can get a list data of Google Sheets based on column names in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, google-sheets-api

I'm modeling data search in Google Sheets using API (EF). I am currently connected to Google Sheets data. I also wrote a search based on `RowId` it's ok. Everything works fine. However I can't find data based on `Id`. Everything I have:

**ItemGoogleSheet.cs**

```
public class ItemGoogleSheet
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ItemsGoogleSheetMapper.cs**

```
public class ItemsGoogleSheetMapper
{
    public static List<ItemGoogleSheet> MapFromRangeData(IList<IList<object>> values)
    {
        var items = new List<ItemGoogleSheet>();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            ItemGoogleSheet item = new()
            {
                Id = value[0].ToString(),
                Name = value[1].ToString(),
            };
            items.Add(item);
        }
        return items;
    }
    public static IList<IList<object>> MapToRangeData(ItemGoogleSheet item)
    {
        var objectList = new List<object>() { item.Id, item.Name };
        var rangeData = new List<IList<object>> { objectList };
        return rangeData;
    }
}
```

**ItemsGoogleSheetVATController.cs**

```
public class ItemsGoogleSheetVATController : ControllerBase
{
    const string SPREADSHEET_ID = "xxxx";
    const string SHEET_NAME = "xx";
    SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource _googleSheetValues;
    public ItemsGoogleSheetVATController(GoogleSheetsHelper googleSheetsHelper)
    {
        _googleSheetValues = googleSheetsHelper.Service.Spreadsheets.Values;
    }
    [HttpGet("{rowId}")]
    public IActionResult GetRowID(int rowId)
    {
        var range = $"{SHEET_NAME}!A{rowId}:AG{rowId}";
        var request = _googleSheetValues.Get(SPREADSHEET_ID, range);
        var response = request.Execute();
        var values = response.Values;
        return Ok(ItemsGoogleSheetMapper.MapFromRangeData(values).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetID(string id)
    {
        //How to get Data from Id
        //return Ok();
    }
}
```

My Google Sheets Data:

[image]

As in my description. I want to find **Id = 0102** then it will output a **list of results of: 0102, 01022101, 01022102**

How can I get list of data based on Id column. Asking for any solutions from everyone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Thank you!